# Oracle BI Publisher Procedural Call

Tags: syntax, call, procedural

Am new to PL/SQL i want print the same code in Oracle BI Publisher Procedural Call.

DECLARE 
message  varchar2(20):= 'Hello, World!'; 
BEGIN 
dbms_output.put_line(message); 
END;

Answer (score 0):

try this instead

```
declare
message varchar2(200) := 'Hello World!';
begin
 fnd_file.put_line(fnd_file.output,message);
end;
```

where message is the same value that u declared before

Comment: Sorry received the below mentioned error (oracle.xdo.servlet.data.DataException: oracle.xdo.servlet.data.DataException: oracle.xdo.servlet.data.DataException: oracle.xdo.XDOException: oracle.xdo.XDOException: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index) and FYI am trying it in Oracle fusion cloud BI Publisher